# Visual Studio skipping multiple if statements?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I'm making a simple maze program that generates a maze. Currently I was working on making one and only solution to a maze, when I stumbled onto something weird. When I debug this code I see that VS is just skipping my if statements here:

```
        for (i = 0; i <= (col * row) / 200; i++)
        {
        solution[se[0]][se[1]] = 1;
        if (lab[se[0] + 1][se[1]]) se[0] + 1;
        else if (lab[se[0]][se[1] + 1]) se[1] + 1;
        else if (lab[se[0] - 1][se[1]]) se[0] - 1;
        else if (lab[se[0]][se[1] - 1]) se[1] - 1;

        solution[se[2]][se[3]] = 1;
        if (lab[se[2] - 1][se[3]]) se[2] - 1;
        else if (lab[se[2]][se[3] - 1]) se[3] - 1;
        else if (lab[se[2] + 1][se[3]]) se[2] + 1;
        else if (lab[se[2]][se[3] + 1]) se[3] + 1;
        }
```

I hope it's not a duplicate, but I have no slightest idea what's the problem here, so it could be one.

Here's the full code if someone wants to replicate the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
int **lab, **solution;
int col, row, i, j;

int main() {
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    col = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left; row = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1; i = 0; j = 0;
    lab = new int* [row];
    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        lab[i] = new int[col];
    solution = new int* [row];
    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        solution[i] = new int[col];

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {           // Build basic maze
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (i == 0) lab[i][j] = 0;
            else if (i == j == 1) lab[i][j] = 1;
            else if (i == 1 && j == col - 1) lab[i][j] = 1;
            else if (i == row - 1) lab[i][j] = 0;
            else if (j == 0) lab[i][j] = 0;
            else if (j == col - 1) lab[i][j] = 0;
            else {
                if (lab[i - 1][j] == 0) lab[i][j] = rand() % 2;
                else {
                    if (lab[i - 1][j - 1] + lab[i - 1][j + 1] + lab[i - 2][j] <= 1) lab[i][j] = 1;
                    else {
                        lab[i][j] = rand() % 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int se[4] = { 1,1,1,col - 1 };

    for (i = 0; i <= (col * row) / 200; i++)        // Generate a solution
    {
        solution[se[0]][se[1]] = 1;
        if (lab[se[0] + 1][se[1]]) se[0] + 1;
        else if (lab[se[0]][se[1] + 1]) se[1] + 1;
        else if (lab[se[0] - 1][se[1]]) se[0] - 1;
        else if (lab[se[0]][se[1] - 1]) se[1] - 1;

        solution[se[2]][se[3]] = 1;
        if (lab[se[2] - 1][se[3]]) se[2] - 1;
        else if (lab[se[2]][se[3] - 1]) se[3] - 1;
        else if (lab[se[2] + 1][se[3]]) se[2] + 1;
        else if (lab[se[2]][se[3] + 1]) se[3] + 1;
    }
    while (se[0] != se[2] || se[1] != se[3])
    {
        if (se[0] < se[2])
        {
            if (lab[se[2] - 1][se[3]]) se[2] - 1;
            if (lab[se[0] + 1][se[1]]) se[0] + 1;
        }
        if (se[1] < se[3])
        {
            if (lab[se[2]][se[3] - 1]) se[3] + 1;
            if (lab[se[0]][se[1] + 1]) se[1] + 1;
        }
        solution[se[0]][se[1]] = 1;
        solution[se[2]][se[3]] = 1;
    }


    std::string out;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {            // Print maze
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (solution[i][j]==1) out.append("@");
            else if (!lab[i][j]) out.append("#");
            else out.append(" ");;
        }
        std::cout << out << '\n';
        out="";
    }

    system("pause");

    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i) delete[] lab[i];
    delete[] lab;
}
```

I'm sorry, this code is a mess, because it's still work in progress.

BTW I'm using VS 2019, didn't try it in another compiler yet. Is it really a compiler's fault?

Comment: "this code is a mess, because it's still work in progress" ... just a friendly suggestion: do it "right" from the beginning. It makes it so much easier to develop iteratively ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why the compiler sees fit to 'skip' the `if` blocks is because there is no code in them that has any effect!

For example, in the statement:

```cpp
if (lab[se[0] + 1][se[1]]) se[0] + 1;
```

when the condition in the test is "true" what happens? The statement `se[0] + 1` doesn't actually modify anything - it is simply an expression that has the given value.

What you *probably* want is to add 1 to `se[0]`, so you need this:

```cpp
if (lab[se[0] + 1][se[1]]) se[0] += 1;
```

and similarly for the other `if` and `else if` lines. (Note the added `=` character!)